# Get URL Contents in Node.js with Express

Tags: node.js, express

How would I go about downloading the contents of a URL in Node when using the Express framework? Basically, I need to complete the Facebook authentication flow, but I can't do this without GETing their OAuth Token URL.

Normally, in PHP, I'd use Curl, but what is the Node equivalent?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/http.html#http.get

Comment: Thanks for the pure-Node solution. While the whole event driven thing is cool, the simplicity of the request module makes the code a lot simpler for the project I'm working with. Because I didn't specify module or module-less, I'm going to mark this as the answer.

Comment: I found the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695143/how-to-make-web-service-calls-in-expressjs to be a better example of the same solution.

Comment: Um?? The question asked for the HTML, not the status code.

Comment: @JackM https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230345/16359609

Answer (score 16):

The problem that you will front is: some webpage loads its contents using JavaScript. Thus, you needs a package, like [After-Load](https://github.com/abdennour/node-afterload) which simulates browser's behavior, then gives you the HTML content of that URL .

```
var afterLoad = require('after-load');
afterLoad('https://google.com', function(html){
   console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken. Here the npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-load

Answer (score 9):

Using http way requires way more lines of code for just a simple html page .

> Here's an efficient way : Use **request**

```
var request = require("request");

request({uri: "http://www.sitepoint.com"}, 
    function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
});
```

Here is the doc for request : https://github.com/request/request

---

#### 2nd Method using fetch with promises :

```
    fetch('https://sitepoint.com')
    .then(resp=> resp.text()).then(body => console.log(body)) ;
```

Comment: As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Using [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module:

```
const http = require('http');

http.get('http://localhost/', (res) => {
    let rawHtml = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawHtml += chunk; });
    res.on('end', () => {
        try {
            console.log(rawHtml);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    });
});
```

`rawHtml` - complete html of the page.

I just simplified [example from official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback).

Answer (score -2):

using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is much simpler

```
const axios = require("axios").default

const response = axios.get("https://google.com")

console.log(response.data)
```

or

```
const axios = require("axios").default

const response = axios.get("https://google.com").then((response)=>{
console.log(response.data)
})
```

for full docs, you can head over [Axios Github](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: Retuns undefined