# php Curl to Nodejs return data

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, curl, meteor

1 I have this code in php , and I  want to code it to javascript in a web aplication with Meteor, please help me to find this code in javascript

```js
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    // Initiate the curl session
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Removes the headers from the output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    // Return the output instead of displaying it directly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // Execute the curl session
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    // Close the curl session
    curl_close($ch);
    // Return the output as a variable
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Do you want this on the client or on the server?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We try to avoid questions which are too broad. Do take a look at the our guide and improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL Contents in Node.js with Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772605/get-url-contents-in-node-js-with-express)

Comment: it helped me , thank you