# Windows Azure SDK - Linux - VHD Export

Tags: ubuntu, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm actually trying to export the vhd of a virtual machine from the glob where it to a 'security' disk somwhere far beyond. There's no problem with anything, imho, since i use the same command to upload/download much smaller files ( < 1Mb vs 31GB circa ) with no problem.

Executing command storage blob download
+ Download blob XXXXX.vhd in container vhds to XXXXX.vhd

Percentage: 1.7% (505.60MB/29.30GB) Average Speed: 11.24MB/S Elapsed Time: 00:00:45

error:   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   storage blob download command failed

ENOTFOUND never comes at the same time ( but afaik, always before 1 minute ) and last dump pages where all like:

```
00:20:36.115638 IP xxx.xx.x.xx.443 > myhost.33879: Flags [R.], seq 1595642065, ack 138757826, win 0, length 0
00:20:36.199235 IP xxx.xx.x.xx.443 > myhost.33852: Flags [R.], seq 2826782426, ack 2369164868, win 0, length 0
00:20:36.306829 IP xxx.xx.x.xx.443 > myhost.33863: Flags [R.], seq 4065426614, ack 1380197071, win 0, length 0
```

with no answer from me.

That's on:

- Azure SDK: 0.7.4 (node: 0.10.25)
- Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)

Still looking around for a solution before bypassing bashCLI and check if/how it works via python or powershell.

Edit:
see

[Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

too

Riedit: 
seems like you MUST take a snapshot, to download large blob.
BUT there's no way to ask for a snapshot in that damned cli.... :|

Answer (score 0):

Azure-CLI does not implement (yet?) any way to snapshot a VHD.