# ENOTFOUND error with express.js (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy, reverse-proxy

whenever I try to do some redirecting to another web page (e.g. google.com) with my nodejs express server it will fail returning the following error:

```
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND google.com
at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

I tried many differend solutions I found on SO (e.g. [Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound))  already. Not even the ones I found on the node.js (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback for example) website won't work.
Right now I am trying the most simple version:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var request = require('request');
app.get('/', function(req,res) {

     var newurl = 'http://google.com/';
     request(newurl).pipe(res);
 });
 app.listen(1337);
```

or this one

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    } else {
        console.log(error, response, body);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works for me. Where are you running it? Could it be that it's that server's restrictions?

Comment: I'm running it on localhost on my office notebook

Comment: What happens if you use `http://www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the internal network limitations constricted external calls.

```
var request = require('request').defaults({'proxy': 'http://myproxy:1234/'});
```

solved the problem