# Set default host and port for ng serve in config file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to know if i can set a host and a port in a config file so I don't have to type

```
ng serve --host foo.bar --port 80
```

instead of just

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 261, accepted):

### Angular CLI 6+

In the latest version of Angular, this is set in [the `angular.json` config file](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config). Example:

```js
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "architect": {
                "serve": {
                    "options": {
                        "port": 4444
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also [use `ng config`](https://angular.io/cli/config) to view/edit values:

```
ng config projects["my-project"].architect["serve"].options {port:4444}
```

### Angular CLI <6

In previous versions, this was [set in `angular-cli.json`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) underneath the `defaults` element:

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "port": 4444,
      "host": "10.1.2.3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To make things easier, you can  specify `0.0.0.0` instead of the host ip to listen on all Ethernet devices. This way both local host and public ip address can be used.

Comment: VS2017 seems to ignore the port setting for some weird reason, but I used this trick with @dman 's addition (0.0.0.0 as host)  to at least enable remote connections.

Comment: It seems that things have changed in recent versions of the CLI (I'm using version 6). [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330606/1063392).

Comment: Is there a way to make this configuration environment specific?

Answer (score 83):

As of right now that feature is not supported, however if this is something that bothers you an alternative would be in your package.json...

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve --host foo.bar --port 80"
}
```

This way you can simply run `npm start`

Another option if you want to do this across multiple projects is to create an alias, which you can potentially name `ngserve` which will execute your above command.

Comment: sorry, foo.bar, refer for what?
UPDATE: i removed it and works, but dont know.

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa replace foo.bar with the the host address you want your app to run on.

Answer (score 35):

You can configure the default HTTP port and the one used by the LiveReload server with two command-line options :

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --live-reload-port 49153`

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 33):

This changed in the latest Angular CLI.

The file name changed to `angular.json`, and the structure also changed.

This is what you should do:

```
"projects": {
    "project-name": {
        ...
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                  "host": "foo.bar",
                  "port": 80
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with @angular/cli version 6.1.5

Comment: Worked for me with @angular/cli version 7.0.6

Comment: Worked for me with @angular/cli version ~15.0.3

Comment: Not working on Angular 15 for me, hmh.

Answer (score 16):

Another option is to run `ng serve` command with the `--port` option e.g

`ng serve --port 5050`  (i.e for port 5050)

Alternatively, the command: `ng serve --port 0`, will auto assign an available port for use.

Comment: The `--port 0`  bit was nice info but I'm not sure it answers the question.

Comment: Liked the --port 0 option which auto assigned the available port to use...

Comment: The question specifically asks how to set it in a config file

Answer (score 13):

We have two ways to change default port number in Angular.

First way is by CLI command:

`ng serve --port 2400 --open`

Second way is by configuration at the location:

`ProjectName\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\schema.json.`

Make changes in schema.json file.

```
{
 "title": "Dev Server Target",
  "description": "Dev Server target options for Build Facade.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "browserTarget": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Target to serve."
    },
    "port": {
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Port to listen on.",
      "default": 2400
    },
```

Comment: You do not want to override or change source files. angular.json is the correct way to override schema defaults, as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you are planning to **run the angular project** in custom **host/IP** and **Port** there is no need of making changes in **config file**

The following command worked for me

```
ng serve --host aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd --port xxxx
```

Where,

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd --> IP you want to run the project
xxx --> Port you want to run the project
```

Example

```
ng serve --host 192.168.322.144 --port 6300
```

Result for me was

[image]

Comment: OP already knows how to specify host/port in CLI (it's in their question) ... they were wanting to control the configuration to not have to include those options every time.

Comment: There was already an answer regarding config.json. I suggested only an alternate way. I appreciates your view @storsoc

Comment: I've tried the CLI approach mention here and for some reason I keep getting the error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 'my.localtestdomain.nl'. I so badly want to debug properly but have yet to find a way to do it

Comment: @Jacques, Kindly refer this answer which is more relavant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691556/10458040

Answer (score 6):

You can save these in a file, but you have to to put it in `.ember-cli` (at the moment, at least); see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1156#issuecomment-227412924

```
{
"port": 4201,
"liveReload": true,
"host": "dev.domain.org",
"live-reload-port": 49153
}
```

edit: you can now set these in angular-cli.json as of commit https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/da255b0808dcbe2f9da62086baec98dacc4b7ec9, which is in build 1.0.0-beta.30

Answer (score 3):

If your are on windows you can do it this way :

1. In your project root directory, Create file run.bat
2. Add your command with your choice of configurations in this file. For Example

> `ng serve --host 192.168.1.2 --open`

3. Now you can click and open this file whenever you want to serve.

This not standard way but comfortable to use (which I feel).

Answer (score 3):

Setting up local name-resolution with `/etc/hosts` isn't too much effort.

- In order to open the `hosts` file for editing, run: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`.
- Then set up a local host-name in there, eg: `127.0.0.1 localho.st`

Then one can configure the `architect` > `serve` section within `angular.json`:

```
"options": {
  "browserTarget": "app:build",
  "liveReload": true,
  "host": "localho.st",
  "port": 8100
},
```

And one might also want to change the `hostname` in `package.json`:

```
ng run app:serve --host=localho.st --port=8100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically have your local ip address open when running ng serve you can do the following:

```
npm install internal-ip-cli --save-dev
ng serve --open --host $(./node_modules/.bin/internal-ip --ipv4)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i put into package.json (running angular 6):

```
{
  "name": "local-weather-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 5000",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Then a plain npm start will pull in the contents of start.  Could also add other options to contents

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C12iY.png)

Only one thing you have to do. Type this in in your Command Prompt:
ng serve --port 4021 [or any other port you want to assign eg: 5050, 5051 etc ]. No need to do changes in files.