# ng serve This page isn't working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I'm running through the angular-cli tutorial, and the NG Live Development server doesn't seem to launch (No response on http://localhost:8080) with no errors in console. This is a blank project with no code created using:

```
ng new test-app
cd test-app
ng serve
```

[image]

I've tried `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201` with multiple ports. I've made sure there is nothing listening on those ports.

Environment: Windows 10 (1709)

```
@angular/cli: 1.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.7
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

[image]

Is there a log that could provide more information? I haven't been able to find anyone having trouble on this basic step. Cheers.

Comment: the message in green tells you that NG is listening on port 8080.  Did you try `http://localhost:8080` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default host and port for ng serve in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762125/set-default-host-and-port-for-ng-serve-in-config-file)

Comment: Yes, sorry the screenshot of the browser is apparently older than the console screenshot. ** Tested and fixed **

Comment: @jmaz for clarity the commands for port and host were suggestions found online, so I tried them and included them, to preempt those answers. I did try adding them directly to .angular-cli.json and same result, thx.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using docker in your machine try deleting all the files in docker desktop,it worked for me

Comment: Not detailed. Please edit.