# Access angular application using IP

Tags: angular, server, ip

I am trying to access my angular application which is running on `http://localhost:4200` . I have tried changing localhost to my actual IPV4 address `192.168.43.XXX` but I m receiving the following message from the browser **"This site can’t be reached"**.

Using `http://127.0.0.1:4200` works just fine.
I am running the application using `ng serve`.

I have tried turning off the firewall but nothing changes.

Is it necessary to run the application like this `ng serve host 192.168.43.XXX` ?

If so, why ?

If I remember correctly I have managed to connect from my phone using only `ng serge` a year ago.

Comment: I don't want my application to  be usable outside my Lan for now, later I will deploy it on a website.  I was trying to connect to http://192.168.43.XXX:4200, so the port was specified.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762125/set-default-host-and-port-for-ng-serve-in-config-file

Answer (score 2):

To access your Angular Web app across computers in the same LAN, you'll need to serve and host your angular App in the CLI as so:

```js
ng serve --host 192.172.0.402 --port 4500
```

Where `192.172.0.402` is your PC's IP address, while `4500` is your custom service port. Your PC will be the server within the LAN.

- Be sure to add your PC IP address to allowed CORS in your `setting.py` esp. when you're dealing with django auths for example.