# calling a third party rest api from node

Tags: node.js, rest, http, basic-authentication

I am developing a simple nodejs application. I am trying to make a REST API call from that application an the REST API has basic authentication. I am getting error **"ERRORError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"** Tried with the options suggested in stackoverflow but couldn't make it work. Can anyone please help me on this..Here is the code I am using  `

```
var http = require('http');

var url = 'someurl';
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var optionsget = {
  host: 'someurl',
  method: 'GET',
  auth: username + ':' + password,
  headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

console.log('Do the GET call');

// do the GET request
var reqGet = http.get(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("Hii");
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error("ERROR" +e);
});
```

Thanks in advance
Regards
VHC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

Comment: thomas.. I have tried all possible ways I found on stackoverflow...I am not able to ping also..I tried pinging www.google.com . Getting connection timed out error for all the pings

Comment: Can you share the url ?

Comment: What is the actual url you are passing?  Is it a fully qualified URL such as `http://somedomain.com/somepath`?

Answer (score 0):

`www.google.com` is not a valid URL.  The browser lets you type it (which tends to make people think it should work in all circumstances), but that's only because under the covers, the browser guesses that you meant to type `http://www.google.com`.

The http module requires a fully qualified URL such as `http://www.google.com` or it requires you to separately specify host and path and protocol in the `options` object.  But, if you're just going to pass a URL, then it needs to be a full URL.  Details in [the node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).

Comment: @user1948228 - Did this answer your question?  If it did, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.