# Server side rendering with Apollo: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, express, react-router, apollo, react-apollo

I'm running Apollo/React with Express and I'm trying to get server side rendering to work. The [Apollo docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/server-side-rendering.html#server-initialization) suggest the following initialisation code for connecting to the API server:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.originalUrl }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
      ssrMode: true,
      networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
        uri: 'http://localhost:3000', // Instead of 3010
        opts: {
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
            cookie: req.header('Cookie'),
          },
        },
      }),
    });

    const app = (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );

    getDataFromTree(app).then(() => {
      const content = ReactDOM.renderToString(app);
      const initialState = {[client.reduxRootKey]: client.getInitialState()  };
      const html = <Html content={content} state={initialState} />;
      res.status(200);
      res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(html)}`);
      res.end();
    });

  });
});
```

which uses the [`match()`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/modules/match.js#L18) function from React Router v3 (as evidenced by [package.json](https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React/blob/master/package.json) in the "GitHunt" example linked from the docs). I'm using React Router v4 from which `match()` is absent, so I refactored the code as follows, using `renderRoutes()` from the [`react-router-config` package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config).

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient(/* Same as above */)

  const context = {}

  const app = (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.originalUrl}>
        { renderRoutes(routes) }
      </StaticRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )

  getDataFromTree(app).then(/* Same as above */)
})
```

My understanding is that `<StaticRouter>` obviates the use of `match()`. However `react-router-config` provides a [`matchRoutes()`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config#matchroutesroutes-pathname) function which seems to provide a similar functionality (albeit without the callback) if needed.

When I visit http://localhost:3000, the page loads as expected and I can follow links to subdirectories (e.g. http://localhost:3000/folder). **When I try to directly load a subdirectory by typing in the name in the address bar,** my browser keeps waiting for the server to respond. After about six seconds, Terminal shows one of the following errors (not sure what causes the error to change on subsequent tries):

> (node:1938) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Network error: request to
>   http://localhost:3000 failed, reason: **getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND** localhost
>   localhost:3000

or

> (node:8691) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Network error: request to
>   http://localhost:3000 failed, reason: **socket hang up**

I've been struggling with this problem for a few hours now, but can't seem to figure it out. The solution to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound) seems unrelated to this case. Any help will be much appreciated!

**Further information**

If I don't kill the nodemon server, after some time I get thousands of the following errors:

> POST / - - ms - -
>
> (node:1938) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4443): Error: Network
>   error: request to http://localhost:3000 failed, reason: **socket hang up**

If I do kill the server, however, I immediately get this error instead:

> /Users/.../node_modules/duplexer/index.js:31
>
> ```
> writer.on("drain", function() {
>
>       ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
>
> at duplex (/Users/.../node_modules/duplexer/index.js:31:11)
>
> at Object.module.exports (/Users/.../node_modules/stream-combiner/index.js:8:17)
>
> at childrenOfPid (/Users/.../node_modules/ps-tree/index.js:50:6)
>
> at kill (/Users/.../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:271:7)
>
> at Bus.onQuit (/Users/.../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:327:5)
>
> at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>
> at Bus.emit (events.js:188:7)
>
> at process. (/Users/.../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:349:9)
>
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
>
> at emitNone (events.js:86:13)

Also, port 3000 is correct. If I change the number, I get a different error instead:

> (node:2056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Network error: request to
>   http://localhost:3010 failed, reason: **connect ECONNREFUSED**
>   127.0.0.1:3010

Comment: Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1:3000` instead of using `localhost`? Also, you should rule out antivirus software and/or firewalls. And make sure there's an entry `127.0.0.1   localhost` in your hosts file.

Comment: I tried both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`, with and without `http://`, but that wasn't it. I also double-checked the entry in my hosts file. However I noticed that the problem only manifests itself when directly visiting subfolders and updated the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Add ssrMode: true to ApolloClient, I had a similar issue and root cause was repeated fetching. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean at `const client = new ApolloClient(/* ... */)`? Because I'm already including `ssrMode: true` there, I just left out the arguments in the second code snippet because they were identical to those in the first one. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What is the node version you are using, and OS?

Comment: Node v7.10.0, macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that the error was due to `renderToString` and `renderToStaticMarkup` not being made available by importing `ReactDOM`.

The import statement `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` had to be replaced by `import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'`.

Also, `uri` had to point to `http://localhost:3000/graphql` instead of `http://localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running your server / project inside a container / containers. I had the same issue as this and ended up doing the following to fix it.

`const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
   uri: process.browser 
         ? 'http://0.0.0.0:1111/graphql' 
         : 'http://my-docker-container-name:8080/graphql'
})`

I have an internal docker network created for my containers in my docker-compose.yml, which allows the containers to communicate with each other, however the browser communicates to the GQL server on a different URL, causing the issue you described on SSR the `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`, so although it was working client side, on the SSR it would fail.

I am using nextJS framework which gives the ability to detect the browser or SSR, i'm sure you could do the same outside of nextJS.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not running my server in (a) container(s).

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for days :)