# Firebase function is not getting triggred. Integration with sendgrid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a firebase functions as below . Problem is it is not getting triggered when I am adding a new user. Please advice me where I am doing mistake.
My exception with below function is that whenever an entry goes to `/user` document, an email should go to the user email. Basically it is a signUp page, for a successful sign-up I would like to send email.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as sendgrid from '@sendgrid/mail';


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'SG.xxxxCfXA46A.6i-lhxxxxxxxxxxx0';
// const sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');

sendgrid.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);



exports.userCreateEmail = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onCreate((event) => {
    const userId = event.params.userId;
    console.info('userId '+userId);
    const db = admin.firestore();
    return db.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then(doc => {
        const user = doc.data();
        console.log(user);
        const msg = {
            to: user.email,
            from: 'asdf@gmail.com',
            subject: 'new follower',
            templateId: 'b98f5d37-8371-4c24-850c-sdfasdf'
        };
        return sendgrid.send(msg);
    }).then(() => console.log('email sent!'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what it's supposed to do, and the change you made that expects it to be invoked.  In particular, you're apparently waiting for a change in Realtime Database, but then doing work in Firestore after that, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If using firebase:

Change this:

```
exports.userCreateEmail = functions.database.ref(`/users`).onCreate((event) => {
```

to this:

```
exports.userCreateEmail = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onCreate((event) => {
```

Also use `'` instead of   `

Also `event.params` will retrieve the value of the wildcard, so you have to add `{//anyname}` as wild card and then you will be able to retrieve it.

Also retrieve the data using `val()` instead of `data()`

If you are using firestore then you need to use this:

```
exports.userCreateEmail = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((event) => {
```

Comment: I made changes as per your comment , still having same issue.

Comment: make sure that the document name is correct, "user" should be the same as the document name in the console @VijayKeshri

Comment: Yes, I am using firestore cloud, If I am making changes exports.userCreateEmail = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}').onCreate( (event) => {

Comment: is this `console.info('userId '+userId);` appearing in the console?

Comment: 1:49:35.796 PM
 info  
userCreateEmail
 

{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.sendgrid.com',
  host: 'api.sendgrid.com',
  port: 443 }

Comment: Yes, console.log is printing userId. I am getting an error on log for sending email.

Comment: 2018-03-09T08:37:32.698Z I userCreateEmail: { uid: 'yzgTbeesSEdgHEFICLFNBljgDPA2',
  photoURL: 'https://lh3.gxxx/photo.jpg',
  email: 'xx@gmail.com',
  displayName: 'xx' }
2018-03-09T08:37:32.932Z I userCreateEmail: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.sendgrid.com',
  host: 'api.sendgrid.com',
  port: 443 }

Comment: @VijayKeshri okay I see, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound