# Cant make http request with intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

So I'm currently trying to have an intent trigger an http request but keep getting errors.

When the intent triggers this code is executed

```
 const https = require('https');
 https.get('*************', 
  (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
    });


    resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
    });


  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
```

When running the intent I get Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND back

My code works fine when I run it locally so the issue appears to be something not lining up properly with dialogflow

If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but that doesnt do the trick, the actual request works fine outside of the dialog flow fulfilment so I'm thinking it must be part of the DF infrastructure.

Comment: Is your Action hosted using Firebase Cloud Functions on the free plan? If so then I believe you are limited to endpoints in Google's cloud.

Comment: What's the IP alias (the *s)? Silly question, but it's not a local server name, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialogflow fulfillments are hosted as firebase cloud functions. Firebase free plan only allows Google service API. If you want to use an external API, you will have to upgrade your plan.

More information can be found here [https://firebase.google.com/pricing/](http://Firebase%20pricing)

Comment: Thank you so much - I spent an embarassing amount of time on that