# Azure Service Bus queue concurrency limit using NodeJS SDK

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am running an Azure function on NodeJS that reads ~4K records from a SQL Server database and sends them to a Service Bus queue using the 'azure-sb' sdk.

If I send the messages sequentially it is too slow. If I use async queues to send many messages in parallel it can go very fast, but it eventually some messages start throwing this error:

> Executed 'Functions.test-function' (Failed,
>   Id=329f0443-e8f6-42ed-92ae-0e9035511635) [08/31/2018 09:04:26]
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.test-function. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
>   [08/31/2018 09:04:26] Exception: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   xxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net:443
>   [08/31/2018 09:04:26] Stack: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net xxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net:443
>   [08/31/2018 09:04:26]     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as
>   oncomplete] (dns.js:50:26).

How can I achieve high throughput with the NodeJS SDK?

Comment: hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691556/7073340) helps

Comment: It is not the case. The service bus occasionally return the error when I'm calling it with a lot of concurrent calls. If I call it slowly or few concurrent calls it never throws the error.