# Yarn break when start serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue-cli

The command yarn run serve breaks, the log error is

```
$ vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...
 10% building 2/2 modules 0 activeevents.js:173                              
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1439:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Sounds like the address is already in use, try using a different port or see what service is already on the given port.

Comment: searching for the error you get, i.e. `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` results in [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. conda deactivate
2. unset HOST (Check the value using $HOST)
3. conda config --set auto_activate_base false