# Calling HTTPS POST API from Firebase Functions - Getting ENOTFOUND Error

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call an external POST API from my firebase function but it's not working as expected. I'm calling the firebase function from my android app. Following are the code snippets for my function, android call and the error that I'm getting in firebase console:

**Firebase Function:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const https = require('https');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.generateToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const variable = data.variable;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    console.log("Function Trigerred");

    if(uid !== null) {
        console.log("UID: " + uid);

        const requestPayload = JSON.stringify({
            "variable": variable
        });

        console.log(requestPayload);

        const config = {
            hostname: 'API-HOST',
            port: 443,
            path: '/API-PATH',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        console.log(config);

        const response = "";

        const req = https.request(config, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                res.send(data);
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.end(error);
        });

        req.write(requestPayload);
        req.end();
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid User");
        res.send("Invalid User");
    }
});
```

**Call in App**

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("variable", "value");
FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
        .getHttpsCallable("generateToken")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith(task -> {
            String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
            Log.e("1: ", result);
            return result;
        })
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            Log.e("2: ", "Complete");
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Exception e = task.getException();
                if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                    FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                    FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                    Object details = ffe.getDetails();
                }
                Log.e("3: ", task.getException().toString());
            }
        });
```

**Firebase Console Log**

```
{
  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND API-HOST API-HOST:443 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete (dns.js:67:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'API-HOST',
  host: 'API-HOST',
  port: 443
}
```

However, when I tried hitting this API from Postman, I got the successful response.

I'm new to Node.js.

Comment: Make sure, you've enabled billing to be able to call external APIs. Check the errors that you get in the logs in firebase console.

Comment: Billing is enabled and I'm not getting any logs in firebase console. That's an additional problem. Also. I don't want to use the port in this API call, is it possible to skip the port specification?

Comment: Hey @EraftYps, I updated the question with logs, please look into this if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

Comment: No, it did not. @EraftYps

Comment: `getaddrinfo` usually refer to a DNS issue, so, can you try changing the hostname to the API server's IP?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.